# How to print a sum of two numbers declared in main and passed as argument to a function sum whose return type is void in main.

Tags: c, function, declaration

My two variables which are to be added are defined in main.

There is a sum function (suppose). Its return type is void.
The variables are passed to this function and I want to print result in main.

Comment: What is the prototype of `sum`? Presumably, as mentioned in the answer below, it takes a pointer as argument that will be used to store the result.

Comment: I mentioned about only two arguments-the values and return type of sum be in void.I didn't think about having a third argument as a pointer.That solves it..

Answer (score 3):

You can define the function like this:

```
void sum( int x, int y, long long int *x_plus_y )
{
    *x_plus_y = ( long long int )x + y;
}
```

Where `x_plus_y` is an "output parameter".

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sum( int x, int y, long long int *x_plus_y )
{
    *x_plus_y = ( long long int )x + y;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    int x, y;

    printf( "Enter two integer numbers: " );
    scanf( "%d%d", &x, &y );

    long long int x_plus_y;

    printf( "Sum of %d and %d is equal to %lld\n", 
        x, y, ( sum( x, y, &x_plus_y ), x_plus_y ) );
}
```